How can I get a listing of my posts with the newest on top?
How can I get a listing of my posts with the newest post on top?
Thanks.

Go to your profile page. Scroll down if needed

Pick the 'newest' link. This will give you a listing of your most recent posts.

If you want further history the questions and answers link on the left will bring you to a page with just those.

Thanks. I want to see how many clearly written posts are unanswered.

@AndrewK That would require you to deep dive in the data explorer to query for unanswered.  The default 'search' on profile, etc. is not going to yield that information for you.
